# How to send a fix recovery request (U2) using the quickfixn library?

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixn

As mentioned here:

https://library.tradingtechnologies.com/tt-fix/recovery/Msg_RecoveryRequest_U2.html

Not able to find a Recovery Request message (U2) type that this library supports, however, in FIX44.xml there is this message type:

```html
<message name="OutOfBandRecoveryRequest" msgcat="app" msgtype="U2">
    <field name="StartDate" required="Y" />
    <field name="EndDate" required="Y" />
    <field name="SecurityExchange" required="N" />
    <field name="ExDestination" required="N" />
</message>
```

How can I build a recovery request to send using quickfixn?

Comment: Where is the FIX44.xml file that you are finding that?  I don't see it in the QF/n source repo's FIX44.xml file.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier U2 request type can be found in `FIX44.xml` file here:
https://library.tradingtechnologies.com/tt-fix/recovery/tt-fix-schema.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you need is the last example of this page: http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/sending-messages.html

You will see the sample fills field by field (including the message type).

You can send and receive messages working with the "generic" types.

[image: Creating messages from scratch]